# PlayStation 4 party chat issue when NAT

Tags: router, nat, playstation

I have an ARRIS CM820B which is in modem mode with public ip address. I hooked up my pc directly to the modem and the pc got the public ip address, so it works fine.

When I connect my PlayStation 4 directly to the modem, the party chat works fine with my friend.

But as I want to use other devices at home, I need a router and here comes the problem.

I tried two different router:

- My main router: Ubiquiti ERPoe-5
- My other router for testing: latest DD-WRT

I have enabled UPNP both of them and UPNP opened up the required ports, but the PlayStation 4 party chat does not worked. Also I have enabled DMZ in DD-WRT, but the result is the same.

I'm sure that both of the router configured fine as I was able to ping the UPNP opened ports from outside also everything else works fine.

Do you have any suggestion what should I check or debug to make the voice chat work?

### UPDATE #1

I have created two packet capture, one on the WAN and one on eth1 where PS4 hooked up. Could you check if you see any strange thing?

WAN: https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/b0d9b2a3d187

PS4: https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/49c235bd7adc

Comment: Could you link source which describes which UPnP revision supported in DD-WRT? It would be great to have flags and instructions for compile too.

Comment: I do not find anything related in Google :(

Comment: There are discussions that talk about this problem.  I solved it by moving away from open source firmware honestly